# Numpy fastest way to apply array of functions to matrix columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of functions shape `(n,)` and a numpy matrix of shape `(m, n)`. Now I want to apply each function to its corresponding column in the matrix, i.e.

```
matrix[:, i] = funcs[i](matrix[:, i])
```

I could do this with a `for` loop (see example below), but using for loops is generally discouraged in numpy. My question is what is the quickest (and preferably most elegant) way to do this?

#### A working example

```
import numpy as np

# Example of functions to apply to each row
funcs  = np.array([np.vectorize(lambda x: x+1),
                   np.vectorize(lambda x: x-2),
                   np.vectorize(lambda x: x+3)])
# Initialise dummy matrix
matrix = np.random.rand(50, 3)

# Apply each function to each column
for i in range(funcs.shape[0]):
    matrix[:, i] = funcs[i](matrix[:, i])
```

Comment: Could you share the actual functions that you are working with?

Comment: Loops are discouraged when you're performing the same operation over and over, but as you're looping over different Python functions here, it may not be possible to make it any faster.

Comment: `funcs  = np.array([np.vectorize(lambda x: x+1),...` looks like you've gone off course. It might be better to take a step back and show what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @Divakar, the functions I am working with are based on [sklearn.cluster.dbscan](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html#sklearn.cluster.dbscan), but vary slightly for a specific task. I think it would become too complex to explain that for the question I have here.

Comment: @roganjosh Care to explain? This is pretty close to what it would be in pure Python, i.e. a list of functions.

Comment: @Denziloe so why use numpy? `vectorize` is basically just a `for` loop, numpy only creates complexity here.

Comment: @roganjosh Probably because the questioner is hoping that there is some kind of numpy-based optimisation, so they're sticking to numpy objects.

Comment: My reasoning is indeed that there is some quicker solution to do my computation in numpy. But as Denziloe suggested, this might just be the quickest to solve using a loop based solution.

Comment: @Denziloe I edited my comment after you replied, but to question your own statement; how is that _not_ going off-course? :)

Comment: @ThijsvanEde Divakar is a master of numpy so you should at least try and explain the problem to them first before assuming that a pure python approach is the only way

Comment: I basically apply the `sklearn.cluster.dbscan` function on each column with a different `metric` parameter, i.e. `minkowski`, `euclidean`. So I get the different predictions for each column. However, this does not change the problem imho.

Comment: If `n` is small compared to `m`, don't worry about speed. A few iterations on a complex task won't hurt performance.

Comment: sklearn.cluster.dbscan is class, though... not a function (and in numpy terms, what you have is an array, not a matrix).

Answer (score 1):

For an array that has many rows and a few columns, a simple column iteration should be time effective:

```
In [783]: funcs = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x+2, lambda x: x+3]
In [784]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [785]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     arr[:,i] = funcs[i](arr[:,i])
     ...:     
In [786]: arr
Out[786]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 4,  6,  8],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [10, 12, 14]])
```

If the functions work with 1d array inputs, there's not need for `np.vectorize` (`np.vectorize` is generally slower than plain iteration anyways.)  Also for iteration like this there's no need to wrap the list of functions in an array.  It's faster to iterate on lists.

A variation on the indexed iteration:

```
In [787]: for f, col in zip(funcs, arr.T):
     ...:     col[:] = f(col)
     ...:     
In [788]: arr
Out[788]: 
array([[ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 5,  8, 11],
       [ 8, 11, 14],
       [11, 14, 17]])
```

I use `arr.T` here so the iteration is on the columns of `arr`, not the rows.

A general observation: a few iterations on a complex task is perfectly good `numpy` style.  Many iterations on simple tasks is slow, and should be performed in compiled code where possible.

Answer (score 1):

A loop is efficient here since the job in the loop is heavy.

A readable solution is just :

```
np.vectorize(apply)(funcs,matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, do you know if there is an equivalent to `apply` in python 3.x?